# Do Silent Condensate Pumps for Air Conditioners exist?

Tags: air-conditioning, pump, condensation

I need to install a Condensate Pump in a new A/C in a bedroom, and there is no choice but to pump the condensate up to a drain on the roof.

The A/C technicians have told me about different types of condensate pumps, but they all seem to make an audible sound on regular basis when the pumping action kicks in, and even though the pumps would be on the outside of the wall of the bedroom, they will be right next to a window that will be next to a bed, so my fear is that the regular sound of the pump will be just loud enough to drive me insane as I wait for the next pumping round to kick in, and the next, and the next...

So I was wondering if there are any silent condensate pumps on the market that are also reliable and that will last for years without requiring maintenance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not, however, the brain is a powerful and mysterious thing with the ability to automatically filter out sounds that occur regularly and pose no danger.  When I moved into my house, I thought the regular train horn blasts would keep me up all night. What I found, was that I almost never even notice the train.

Comment: Besides a downstairs neighbor, what is below the air conditioner?  Is there no drain or soil?

Comment: @Tester101 I had an aircon unit on the wall of my bedroom and I can testify that, no, your brain won't filter out a loud condensate pump.  It will wake you up rudely.  I eventually just left the aircon off at night.  DON'T have a condensate pump in the bedroom or preferably any room, have it somewhere the noise will be blocked.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer. In my experience as an HVAC technician:

There is no completely silent condensate pump on the market that Me or my Suppliers are aware of. If there was, everyone would be buying them.

There are however certain pumps on the market that are designed to take into consideration sound level. The quietest pump i have ever come across is the [DiversiTech ClearVue Condensate Pump](http://www.diversitech.com/Product-Line?id=a0jC0000005QEykIAG). They have great build quality along with all DiversiTech products, and also has a built in alarm and over flow sensor that can be wired into your HVAC system to stop operation of the air conditioner if there ever is a blockage in the discharge line, or if the pump should fail for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm exploring purchasing one of these, but wanted to know if after 7 years you had encountered any other models which are the same or better?

Answer (score 2):

Just because you need a pump does not mean that the pump has to be right next to the air conditioner. As long as you don't exceed the vertical pumping abilities of the pump and the run from the AC to the pump is downhill, you could put it farther along the wall or even around the corner.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an apartment building, so I can't go very far or I the neighbors will be hearing it more than me.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the a/c unit on an outside wall or a wall backing onto a bathroom, loo or kitchen.  Install a gravity condensate drain from the /ac unit to the nearest drain.

I did this with a Daikin unit in my bedroom and without the condensate pump going off every few minutes it is whisper quite and I sleep soundly.